# drag/move JFrame/JDialog window from content area

Tags: java, swing

drag a jframe window from it's content area is simple, but here is the problem.
when i added a label onto the frame, it's still ok even drag on the label, 
but when i add mouseclicked event for the label, even no codes actually proccessed in the adapter, the dragging can't happen when i drag on the label, but drag on the rest area of the window is fine.

another thing is I want to make the window's opacity varies with the mouse motion,
with this.setOpacity(0.9f);
after the label's mouseclicked event set, the label won't respond to this also..

anyone knows how the solve this?

```
private void formMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    offsetX = evt.getX();
    offsetY = evt.getY();
}

private void formMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    java.awt.Component c = (Component) evt.getSource();
    c.setLocation(evt.getXOnScreen() - offsetX, evt.getYOnScreen()- offsetY);
}

private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // nothing actually done in the Label's mouse handler
}

private void formMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    this.setOpacity(0.9f);
}

private void formMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    this.setOpacity(0.4f);
}
```

Comment: I see a couple questions. Pick **one** and make [a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) replicating the problem, so we can test out.

Comment: `// TODO add your handling code here:`  Remove these comments once you've added some handling code or a comment as to why it is not implemented!  They are noise.

Comment: What you want to do can be better implemented in a `JGlassPane`. You do not have to write listeners for each component in the `JFrame`. You only write one mouse listener for the `JGlassPane` and then implement the opacity changing code and the `jframe` moving code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's still ok even drag on the label, but when i add mouseclicked event for the label, even no codes actually proccessed in the adapter

Correct, the MouseEvent is only passed to one component, so the label stops the event from being passed to the window.

So you need to add the MouseListener to the window and the label in order to drag the window.

Check out [Moving Windows](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/). It is a listener that will allow you to move any component relative to its parent. So you can create a `ComponentMover` and then register the root pane of your window to allow you to drag the window. But you will also need to register the label.

Comment: camickr, thanks a lot! the class is cool! i can move with any component now, but the opacity setting is only working when enter/exit the window, but not working with the label, any idea on this?

Comment: alright, it's cool, by adding mouseEntered/mouseExited, i'm able to do the opacity thing. thanks a lot!